# Rigid monohedral tilers

Tags: discrete-geometry, tiling

Say that a tile $T$ that alone can tile the plane—a monohedral tile—is ***rigid***
if it is *not* the case that $T$ can be slightly deformed to $T'$ so that:

- $T'$ can also tile the plane
- $T'$ is arbitrarily close to $T$, say, according to Hausdorff distance.
- The tiling by $T'$ is "combinatorially equivalent."

For example, the familiar regular hexagon tiling is *not* rigid, because it can
be "compressed" vertically:

---

### [image: SquashedHex]

Rigid tilers are "brittle" in that even a slight deformation changes their tiling properties.
Since all triangles and all quadrilaterals are monohedral tilers,
it is not difficult to claim that no $n\in\{3,4\}$-sided polygons are rigid tilers.

Questions:

- **Q1** Has this notion of a "rigid tiler" been explored?
- **Q2** Which of the [$15$ pentagonal monohedral tilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling) are rigid?

Clearly the pentagonal **cmm (2*22)** tiler is not rigid, because the pentagon tile is simply a hexagon split vertically:

[image: cmm (2*22)]

   [Wikipedia image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling#/media/File:P5-type1_p4g.png)